# "bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory" when running shell script

Tags: raspbian, script

I wrote a shell script for my Raspberry Pi and made it executable. When I run `./filename.sh`, I see an error:

```
bash: ./filename.sh: bin/bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I wrote this script in the default directory (`/home/pi`). After the error occurred, I put a copy of the script on my desktop but I see the same error.

What is the problem and solution?

Comment: Do you think it would be easier to help you if you actually included the script that you wrote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A script is running without its interpreter when it is made executable and contains a **shebang** at the very first line. Because your script is running I assume that's the case with your script. But the error message shows that you miss the leading slash in the path to *bash*. Your **shebang** should look as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
```